# pandas: from how to unpack nested JSON as dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an JSON output like this

`json.json`

```
{"SeriousDlqin2yrs": {"prediction": "0", "prediction_probs": {"0": 0.95, "1": 0.04}}}
{"SeriousDlqin2yrs": {"prediction": "0", "prediction_probs": {"0": 0.96, "1": 0.03}}}
```

and I would like to read it in as a pandas dataframes that looks like this

```
prediction, prediction_probs.0, prediction_probs.1
0, 0.95, 0.04
0, 0.96, 0.03
```

but I can't seem to find the right way

I tried

```
predictions = pd.read_json("json.json", lines=True)
predictions.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x[0]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested in pandas `1.1.1` - convert values to `list`s and pass to [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
s = pd.read_json('json.json', lines=True)['SeriousDlqin2yrs'].tolist()

df = pd.json_normalize(s)
print (df)
  prediction  prediction_probs.0  prediction_probs.1
0          0                0.95                0.04
1          0                0.96                0.03
```

Another idea is parsing json to list instead `pd.read_json`:

```
import json

s = []
with open('json.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        s.append(json.loads(line)['SeriousDlqin2yrs'])
        
df = pd.json_normalize(s)
print (df)
  prediction  prediction_probs.0  prediction_probs.1
0          0                0.95                0.04
1          0                0.96                0.03
```