# Parse dictionary inside dataframe

Tags: pandas, dictionary, nan

One column of my df has either 1.a nested dictionary or 2. NAN as value
The dicts has 2 key-value pairs like this one

```
{'value': '1', 'info': {....}}
```

I wish to only get the value of “value”, the value of “info” is not useful, we can leave “NAN” if it is NAN value
What is the easiest way to achieve this?

BTW I tried `df_september_p1['that_column_name']==np.nan`
and        `df_september_p1['that columnname']==’nan’,`
which yield the same Boolean values. The weird thing is I see the 2nd row has NAN as value but the yield result is False for 2nd row… don’t get why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) working well with dictioanries or with missing values `NaN`s:

```
df_september_p1['val'] = df_september_p1['that_column_name'].str.get('value')
```

Comment: BTW do you know the reply to my 2nd question?

Comment: @neutralname - I think yes, for compare is necessary use special functons like [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html), not `==NaN`

Comment: Thanks, BTW I tried the same code with a similar column but seems we can't get several values in one go? I wrote : df_september_p1[['id_CB','CB_name','direction']] = df_september_p1['networkPoint'].str.get('id','name','direction') and get TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: @neutralname - If need all data parsed you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64119012/2901002) solution